# What is a tower?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, terminology

In many tensorflow tutorials ([example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py)) "towers" are mentioned without a definition. What is meant by that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to tensorflow documentation about CNN,

> The first abstraction we require is a function for computing inference and gradients for a single model replica. In the code we term this abstraction a "tower".

To get the relevant context and more, check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/).

Comment: The linked page does not mention "tower" anymore :/

Comment: To keep it simple, a "Tower" is a copy of your model. In a multi-GPU case, if you have 8 GPUs, then you will get 8 Towers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following definition from ML glossary [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary#tower) intuitive:

> Tower - A component of a deep neural network that is itself a deep neural network without an output layer.